# How to show sub-menu in a block?

Tags: 7, navigation

I have a menu in Drupal 7 with 2 main links like home and about us, but I have 3 sub menu in about us like

- About us

  - About Us 1
  - About Us 2

I need to show these 2 submenu in a block and show active when about1 same for about2.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds as if you need the [Submenu Tree](https://www.drupal.org/project/submenutree) module.

This is an excerpt form the project page:

> Submenu Tree provides a method for structuring content hierarchically. For content which has a menu link, Submenu Tree display a list of content which is at the same level or below the content in the menu.

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: no this mdoule show submenu on main menu.. But I need to show only submenu in a block.

Comment: According to project page you should be able to show this in a block as well: `Lists of sub or sibling content can be displayed either in a block or directly inside of the body of a piece of content.`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I dun get what you mean block. Just wonder will tb mega menu module help you. Check this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnuhbFwsJ3M

Answer (score 0):

You can use the superfisch module. https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish

Set the about menu entry to expand by default, so when you hover over menu item about you will see about1, about2.

The superfisch menu can be used in any block.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like [Menu block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) is all you need.